# Does Twitter provide any api for reply a tweet or get list of replies

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitterapi-python, sttwitterapi

I want to integrate Twitter api in my application but I didn't find reply to a Tweet api in developers docs provided by Twitter. How can I get list of replies on a tweet or how can I reply to a tweet?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in Twitter API v2 [using the `conversation_id` operator](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/conversation-id) in search. There's no easy way to do this in the legacy v1.1 API. This [blog post](https://shkspr.mobi/blog/2020/08/omg-twitter-release-an-official-conversations-api/) may help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AndyPiper i have also searched the v2 api of twitter but i didn't find anything relevant and i want to get list of users who likes my tweets, list of users who quoted retweet on my tweets and also want to reply the user who replied on my tweet can you help me in this or is there any api for this on twitter docs.

Comment: So I literally linked to how you can do this in v2 with search.

Comment: This does not apply to likes, your question was around replies.